# TFS 2010 sorting ALLOWED VALUES desc

Tags: tfs-workitem

I'm using TFS 2010. 
I have a string field with a list of allowed values. When I view the work item the list is sorted alphabetically (the original list is not sorted alphabetically).
Is there any way to display the vaule order as the same given in the work item template. 
Is there any way to change the sort order to desc?

I know I can write a custom control for this but I was wondering if there was any easier way.

thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way to sort a list of values (allowed, suggested, or even taken from a global list) in any order, but ascending alphabetically.

You *do* have two option though:

1. Add an index before each item on the list. This index would be something like "1. Banana", "2. Apple", etc. It would be permanent and would appear in the display of the list, but it is the simplest solution, if it's good enough for you.
2. You may create a custom control, that would appear as a drop down list, and would sort by a custom parameter that you can add to the **work item type definition**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I have no choice but to write a custom control. Do you know if I can access a global list (to fill the items) from the custom control?

Comment: Yes, you can. I'm not at my office right now, so I don't have a ready code sample, but you can definitely use the TFS API to access a global list. You do it with the WorkItemTracking service, IIRC.